# better reference for apparently undocumented latex command line options?

Tags: pdftex

I've gradually blundered upon a number of useful pdflatex command line options from questions in this forum, but not all of these are [documented](http://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/pdftex.html) (specifically the useful `-file-line-error` parameter).  My command line now includes the following "goodies"

```
pdflatex -file-line-error -synctex=1 --max-print-line=1000 -interaction batchmode
```

Is there a better manual for the command line options than the url given?  I am using MikTex 2.9 which matches the document url.

If this is the best that the docs get, are there more similar undocumented options that are commonly used and helpful?

Comment: Note that the command line options depend on the distribution. The TeX Live binaries support a different set than MiKTeX, and that's just the two main distributions. However, these both seem to support the different spelling used by the other distribution.

Comment: `texdoc pdflatex` seems pretty good...

Comment: that doesn't work for me (although `texdoc pdftex` does).  However, there's still nothing there for `-file-line-error`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `pdftex -help` helps on my system.  Of course, this is just a short summary.

Comment: It appears that with MikTex 2.9 this is missing any reference to `-file-line-error` (like the web docs)